# Combining loop with awk

Tags: for-loop, awk, while-loop

I need help combining an awk with a loop.

I have two files, one `Bedfile.bed` and a `Samplelist.txt` that look like this:

**Bedfile.bed**

```
HiC_scaffold_2  1       50001

HiC_scaffold_2  400001  450001

HiC_scaffold_2  800001  850001
```

**Samplelist.txt**

```
sampleA
sampleB
sampleC
```

I would like to create a new `Bedfile` for each sample (from the `Samplelist.txt`) in which I include the sample name as a new column next to each line, and I add the name in the output. Looking like this, e.g., for the first two sample

**Bedfile_SampleA.bed**

```
HiC_scaffold_2  1       50001 SampleA

HiC_scaffold_2  400001  450001 SampleA

HiC_scaffold_2  800001  850001 SampleA
```

**Bedfile_SampleB.bed**

```
HiC_scaffold_2  1       50001 SampleB

HiC_scaffold_2  400001  450001 SampleB

HiC_scaffold_2  800001  850001 SampleB
```

I have done this for one file but I have more than a hundred files, so I would like to do some sort of loop using a sample list.

```
awk ' {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t""SampleA"}' Bedfile.bed >  Bedfile_SampleA.bed
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, sorry. there should be a third file with sampleC. I was just lazy to add it in the example

Comment: Do you really want `sample` from the input converted to `Sample` in the file names and output?

Comment: Do you really have blank lines between each data line in your Bedfile files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the operation and the loop all in AWK, but if you wanted to do the loop 'separately' for another reason, you could use:

```
while read -r sample
do
     awk -v var="$sample" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $0, var}' bedfile.bed > bedfile_"$sample".bed
done < samplelist.txt
```

Comment: That won't produce the posted desired output from the posted sample input (note how the blank lines should be copied as-is). Also, make sure to read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) if you're considering using a shell loop to process text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested improvements @EdMorton, you are obviously correct and your answer to the question is perfect (+1). In practice I've never seen a blank line in a bed file and I thought it might be worth offering another solution to kvantour's AWK answer, just in case it's not an XY problem. Thanks for providing so much good feedback on SO; you are one of my favourite users on this site :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR==FNR { samples[$0]; next }
    FNR == 1 {
        base = FILENAME
        sub(/\..*/,"",base)
    }
    {
        for ( sample in samples ) {
            out = base "_" sample ".bed"
            print $0 (NF ? OFS sample : "") > out
        }
    }
' Samplelist.txt Bedfile.bed
```

```
$ head Bedfile_*
==> Bedfile_sampleA.bed <==
HiC_scaffold_2  1       50001   sampleA

HiC_scaffold_2  400001  450001  sampleA

HiC_scaffold_2  800001  850001  sampleA

==> Bedfile_sampleB.bed <==
HiC_scaffold_2  1       50001   sampleB

HiC_scaffold_2  400001  450001  sampleB

HiC_scaffold_2  800001  850001  sampleB

==> Bedfile_sampleC.bed <==
HiC_scaffold_2  1       50001   sampleC

HiC_scaffold_2  400001  450001  sampleC

HiC_scaffold_2  800001  850001  sampleC
```

The above will work in any awk, assuming you don't have too many output files to exceed the "too many open files" limit. If you do, it'll still work with GNU awk, and there's a simple tweak to make it work with any awk.

Answer (score 1):

Thus is very straightforward in awk. First you read the sample file in memory, and then you process the full bed-file

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}(FNR==NR){a[$0]; next}{for(i in a){f=FILENAME"."i; print $0,i > f}}' sample.txt bed.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this command but now I just get a print of the original bed file on the screen. How do you combine it and output in a new file?

Comment: @Andrea I've forgot to redirect the output. The fix is in place.

Comment: That would add `sample<X>` to every blank line and the output file names wouldn't be what was requested in the question, they'd be `bed.txt.sample<X>` instead of `Bedfile_sample<X>.bed`

Comment: @EdMorton I do not believe that the empty records are actual part of the question but more a typo due to copy-pasting (i see it often here). The formatting of the filenames is just some beautification.

Comment: I'd agree on the blank lines if all files had them but one of the input files has them while the other doesn't which makes me think they're deliberate. I could be wrong of course, I've now asked the OP in a comment. Regarding the file names - yeah, but it has a non-trivial impact on the code (adds nearly 50% more code!) once you factor in efficiency.